# Why is Vi is removing my quotations on save?

Tags: npm, vi

I am trying to set up my _auth for npm.

I run `npm config edit` which pulls up the Vi editor. I update the token to include quotes around it

```
_auth="mytokenhere"
```

but then after saving and looking at the file again, it shows up like:

```
_auth=mytokenhere
```

Anyone know why it is not saving my quotes?

To save, I am doing the following:

'Esc' + ':' + 'x' + enter

Comment: no warnings, and it appears to be saving for anything non quotation related. But your response is incorrect according to this guide I followed https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-vim-save-quit-exit ... the guide claims it is universal for vi and vim... maybe that isn't the case?

Comment: I take it back, you're right. It's `q`'s behavior that I'm thinking of, not `x`.

Comment: My workaround to add these quotes was to go into the .npmrc file (the npm config) and manually add the quotes, instead of attempting to do so with vi.